# Eliminate constant to form differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to eliminate the constant $C, D$ form $y=C\cos(x)+D\cosh(x)$ and form an ODE. By taking derivative of $y$ w.r.t $x$, we have $y'=-C\sin(x) + D\sinh(x)$, and then $y''=-C\cos(x) + D\cosh(x)$. But from here I coldn't eliminate $C, D$. Any advice, thanks.

Comment: what happens when you take $y+y''$ and $y-y''$?

Comment: Should  be $y''''-y=0$ with some specific initial conditions.

Comment: @user577215664 but it has only two arbitrary constant, so it should satisfy 2nd order D.E, but yes if we break it $\cos(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ into exponential , then may be it justify the fourth order.